# Delete an element in the linked-list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to delete an element in the linked list with the "price", that is more than "b". In this list elements are being added at the beginning. Unfortunately, my work does not work properly: when I am trying to delete only 1 element, it deletes all the elements, that were added at then beginning. Sorry for my bad English, it is not my first language
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Equipment
{
  char name[20];
  double price;
  char date[20];
  Equipment* next;
} *eq[60];

void add_eq (int m) {
  for ( m = 0; m < 1; m++)
  {
    
    cout << "Enter the name of eq: " << endl;
    eq[m] = new Equipment();
    cin >> eq[m] -> name;
    cout << "Enter the price of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> eq[m] -> price;
    cout << "Enter the date of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> eq[m] -> date;
    cout << "The first eq was added." << endl;
  }
}

void add_el_beg(Equipment*& head, int n) {
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    Equipment* new_el_beg = new Equipment;
    cout << "Enter the name of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> new_el_beg -> name;
    cout << "Enter the price of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> new_el_beg -> price;
    cout << "Enter the date of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> new_el_beg -> date;
    new_el_beg->next = head;
    head = new_el_beg;
    cout << "Інструмент було успішно додано в список. " << endl;
  }
}

void print_list(Equipment* head, int n, int m) {
  int i;
  Equipment* current = head;
  while (current != nullptr) {
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << current->name << " " << current->price << " " << current->date << endl;
      current = current->next;
    }
    for ( m = 0; m < 1; m++)
    {
      cout << eq[m] -> name << " " << eq[m] -> price << " " <<  eq[m] -> date << endl;
    }
  }
}

void del_el(Equipment*& head, int& n, double b) {
    Equipment* current = head;
    Equipment* prev = nullptr;
    b = 100;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->price > b) {
            if (prev == nullptr) { 
                head = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = head;
            } else {
                prev->next = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = prev->next;
            }
            n--;
        } else {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    current = head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        cout << current->name << " " << current->price << " " << current->date << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main() {
  int n, k, m;
  int i, j;
  double b;
  double price;
  char date[20];
  Equipment* head = nullptr;
cout << "Enter the value of eq: " << endl;
  cin >> n;
  int c = 7;
  while (c != 6)
  {
    cout << "Enter your option (1-5): ";
    cin >> c;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 1: 
    add_eq(m);
    add_el_beg(head, n);
      break;
    case 2:
    print_list(head, n, m);
      break;
    case 3:
    del_el(head, n, b); 
    break;
    
    default: cout << "Wrong!" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: For testing purposes I'd highly recommend programmatically setting up your runner i.e. instead of asking for user input, it just populates all the data for you. That makes two things happen: i) you can iterate faster and ii) you can better test the individual functions and components of your code

Comment: yes, I think so, but, unfortunately, the task is to do it from user input, so my professor will not allow me to do it

Comment: IanQ is saying _temporarily_ hardcode some values so you can focus on testing your code. It's way faster than entering information by hand each test iteration. Once your code is working, bring back the user input.

Comment: not an error, but declaring `m` in `main` and passing it to functions by-value uninitialized is completely useless. You can just declare and use it in the functions that need it.

Comment: You post this as C++, but you're using linked list in an array of fixed size. Is this homework? Because if it's not, you'd better reconsider using container classes.
In 'add_eq' you instantly overwrite the value of hte parameter 'm' etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is should work for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Equipment
{
  char name[20];
  double price;
  char date[20];
  Equipment* next;
} *eq[60];

void add_eq (int m) {
  for ( m = 0; m < 1; m++)
  {
    
    cout << "Enter the name of eq: " << endl;
    eq[m] = new Equipment();
    cin >> eq[m] -> name;
    cout << "Enter the price of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> eq[m] -> price;
    cout << "Enter the date of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> eq[m] -> date;
    cout << "The first eq was added." << endl;
  }
}

void add_el_beg(Equipment*& head, int n) {
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    Equipment* new_el_beg = new Equipment;
    cout << "Enter the name of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> new_el_beg -> name;
    cout << "Enter the price of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> new_el_beg -> price;
    cout << "Enter the date of eq: " << endl;
    cin >> new_el_beg -> date;
    new_el_beg->next = head;
    head = new_el_beg;
    cout << "Інструмент було успішно додано в список. " << endl;
  }
}

void print_list(Equipment* head, int n, int m) {
  int i;
  Equipment* current = head;
  while (current != nullptr) {
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << current->name << " " << current->price << " " << current->date << endl;
      current = current->next;
    }
    for ( m = 0; m < 1; m++)
    {
      cout << eq[m] -> name << " " << eq[m] -> price << " " <<  eq[m] -> date << endl;
    }
  }
}

void del_el(Equipment*& head, int& n, double b) {
    Equipment* current = head;
    Equipment* prev = nullptr;
    b = 100;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->price > b) { 
                prev->next = current->next;
                current = current->next;
            n--;
        } else {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    current = head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        cout << current->name << " " << current->price << " " << current->date << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main() {
  int n, k, m;
  int i, j;
  double b;
  double price;
  char date[20];
  Equipment* head = nullptr;
cout << "Enter the value of eq: " << endl;
  cin >> n;
  int c = 7;
  while (c != 6)
  {
    cout << "Enter your option (1-5): ";
    cin >> c;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 1: 
    add_eq(m);
    add_el_beg(head, n);
      break;
    case 2:
    print_list(head, n, m);
      break;
    case 3:
    del_el(head, n, b); 
    break;
    
    default: cout << "Wrong!" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to analyze your code and this is a bit difficult to understand. I realize that this is a kind of homework. It seems that you are mixing two things in your implementation: a static array of pointers to `Equipment` of size 60 and at the same time a dynamically linked list of `Equipment` elements. I believe, that you have probably encountered some undesirable side effects while testing your code. I recommend that you ignore your results and clean up your code first. Remove everything that is not necessary. Read the text of your assignment again and find out what the actual task is. By the way, the code fragment where you delete items inside your linked list seems ok to me, I don't think that is the erroneous part of your code.

Comment: @cigien if you feel my answer is too long or inappropriate, please mention it in a comment instead of changing anything without being asked. i think this question is far too irrelevant to be too elaborate. thanks for reading, if you did.